# Possible to keep a method from showing up in intellisense?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, intellisense

Say I have a class and I want to deprecate a method.  Is it possible to have that method not show up in intellisense so that people won't be temped to use it?  I just want existing code that uses it to continue compiling but hide the method from view at the same time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The EditorBrowsableAttribute attribute can be used to hide members from intellisense:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you can use the System.ObsoleteAttribute. It still might be a good idea to have the method show up in intellisense, since technically it exists.

Using this attribute will show the method name in the intellisense, but with a `[deprecated]` tag in front of it.

```
[Obsolete("Method is in the process of deprecation.")]
void MyMethod() {...}
```

If you use ReSharper, and tell it to override Visual Studio's Intellisense settings, it will strikethrough the method name.

Comment: Does regular Intellisense do the strikethrough?  I thought that was a Resharper feature.